# Combine bfill() and ffill() functionality

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following `pd.Series`:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     4.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     7.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    1.0
11    NaN
12    NaN
13    6.0
14    NaN
15    NaN
```

I'm trying to obtain a Series where the `NaNs` are equally filled by the surrounding valid samples. So say I have `N` `NaNs` between two valid samples, I would like the first `N/2` `NaNs` to be filled by the last valid sample, and the last `N/2` `NaNs` to be filled using the next valid observation. In the case `(N % 2) =! 0`, the extra observation could be filled by either of the two surrounding ones, whichever rule applies is ok. So I would like to obtain:

```
0     4
1     4
2     4
3     4
4     7
5     7
6     7
7     7
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    6
13    6
14    6
15    6
```

Comment: No, @sotos , that would  only use `ffill()`, and fill the remaining `NaNs` at the beginning with `bfill()`

Comment: yes, I re-read the question :)

Comment: while loop + ffill + bfill with limit =1

Comment: @nixon that is why I mentioned `while loop`

Comment: Added solution, please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create boolean mask and filter `bfill` with [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html), then `ffill` and last `bfill` again only for first values of first Series if starting by `NaN`:

```
m = df['A'].notna()
c = m.cumsum()

def f(x):
    lens = len(x.index)
    a = np.arange(lens)
    return a // (lens / 2) == 0

mask = c[~m].groupby(c).transform(f)
#should be removed
#mask = mask.reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
df['B'] = df['A'].where(mask, df['A'].bfill()).ffill().bfill()
print (df)
      A    B
0   NaN  4.0
1   NaN  4.0
2   4.0  4.0
3   NaN  4.0
4   NaN  7.0
5   7.0  7.0
6   NaN  7.0
7   NaN  7.0
8   NaN  1.0
9   NaN  1.0
10  1.0  1.0
11  NaN  1.0
12  NaN  6.0
13  6.0  6.0
14  NaN  6.0
15  NaN  6.0
```

Comment: This is brilliant @jezrael, really nice way to solve it. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is pretty clever, and I was curious how fast this was so I benchmarked it a bit... the short answer is not very (I put the timings in the answer below). I wonder if it's possible to speed it up at all?

Answer (score 2):

I found this an interesting problem. I got pretty close with this code (in a more vectorised/Pandorable way), maybe one of the more experienced people on here could help with the last step:

```
s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 4,np.nan, np.nan, 7, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 6, np.nan, np.nan])
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df2 = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
grouped = df2.groupby((df2.index.to_series().diff() > 1).cumsum())
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for group in grouped:
    test = group[1].reset_index()
    test['fill'] = pd.qcut(test.iloc[:,0], 2, labels=['ff', 'bf'])
    df3 = pd.concat([df3, test])
df3.set_index('index', inplace=True)
pd.merge(df, df3, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True).drop(columns=['0_y'])
```

Output:

```
    0_x     fill

0   NaN     ff
1   NaN     bf
2   4.0     NaN
3   NaN     ff
4   NaN     bf
5   7.0     NaN
6   NaN     ff
7   NaN     ff
8   NaN     bf
9   NaN     bf
10  1.0     NaN
11  NaN     ff
12  NaN     bf
13  6.0     NaN
14  NaN     ff
15  NaN     bf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
while pd.isnull(my_series).sum() > 0:
    my_series = my_series.fillna(method='ffill', limit=1).fillna(method='bfill', limit=1)
```

To say that this will be slow is probably an understatement. If you wanted to do this over a large DataFrame, I'd probably try to implement it with a function that I could use `apply` on.

I never really came up with a good idea for doing this (but I've been keeping an eye on this cause it's an interesting problem). I like the other answer for cleverness, but I was curious how it fared for speed.

```
def funcA(pd_series):
    m = pd_series.notna()
    c = m.cumsum()
    def f(x):
        lens = len(x.index)
        a = np.arange(lens)
        return a // (lens / 2) == 0
    mask = c[~m].groupby(c).transform(f)
    #should be removed
    #mask = mask.reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
    return pd_series.where(mask, pd_series.bfill()).ffill().bfill()

def funcB(pd_series):
    while pd.isnull(pd_series).sum() > 0:
        pd_series = pd_series.fillna(method='ffill', limit=1).fillna(method='bfill', limit=1)
    return pd_series

ps = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,10, size=(10000)))
ps[ps < 5] = np.nan

>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('funcA(ps)', setup='from __main__ import funcA, ps', number=100)
40.9788393480012
>>> timeit.timeit('funcB(ps)', setup='from __main__ import funcB, ps', number=100)
0.4896140840010048
```

Well... that's not nearly as good as I was expecting tbh. Smallish series with half NaN might not be a great test, so maybe try something the while loop should choke on?

```
ps = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(1000000)))
ps[ps < 95] = np.nan

>>> timeit.timeit('funcA(ps)', setup='from __main__ import funcA, ps', number=10)
81.64654629600045
>>> timeit.timeit('funcB(ps)', setup='from __main__ import funcB, ps', number=10)
21.431495654000173
```

Well, that's closer at least. I'm too lazy to scale it up any more, but it looks like you'd need probably 10^7 entries with 95%+ NaN before the extra overhead from masking and arranging pays off.

Comment: As you mention it will be slow for large Series filled with `NaNs`. But worth taking into account, thanks a lot for sharing your approach